# Ecommerce tool for selling services

Tags: php, mysql, e-commerce

I am looking for a good eCommerce CMS.

I need to be able to sell services and products, it must be open source that it can be customised wherever needed.

I am very familiar with PHP and Mysql, and somewhat familiar with python and ruby, so a PHP solution would be preferred.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some of the best PHP carts:

[Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com) - Full featured. Excellent code quality. Hard to learn. Requires lots of server resources.

[PrestaShop](http://www.prestashop.com/) - PrestaShop is currently used by 250,000 shops worldwide and is available in 60 different languages.

[OpenCart](http://opencart.com) - OpenCart comes with an inbuilt Affiliate system, where affiliates can promote specific products and get paid for this.

[InterSpire](http://www.interspire.com/shoppingcart/) - Not Free.

[FoxyCart](http://foxycart.com) - Not Free. Hosted checkout that uses your templates. Works well with a CMS like Modx or Expression Engine.

[LemonStand](http://lemonstandapp.com/) - Not Free.

Comment: Magento is the way to go, the Hard to Learn learning curve is extremely worth it and after some years playing around with it will make it possible for you to sit down for Magento Certification. Which will really feel good to achieve :)

Answer (score 4):

I have two recommendations for you.

1. Dont use OSCommerce.
2. Dont use XTCommerce which is based on OSCommerce

To be more specific **NEVER** **EVER** use oscommerce for **ANY** project you want to extend at all. If you run the project 100% out-of-box and need some payment extension that nobody features consider it for two seconds but then better DONT. OSCommerce features code from 2001. OSCommerce has only one coding pattern which is FIXHACKCOPYQUICKPASTEHERENOW. Its the negation of everything you think to know from software development and project mangement. If you use OSCommerce and try to extend it your project will need twice as long and you will start hating webdevelopment. And yes i know it sounds like, but i am not kidding. Been there, done that.
If anybody tells you to use oscommerce - e.g. for all the existing extentions that are out there - stand up and leave the room.

#### Extra Tipps:

Magento IS SLOW.

- http://www.prestashop.com/ - In the OSS world Prestashop has some popularity.
- http://www.interspire.com/shoppingcart/ has some reputation but is not OSS.

Comment: Agreed.. I hereby confirm the above statement tenfold

Answer (score 1):

I know you want to stick with Linux based but nopCommerce is amazing:
http://www.nopcommerce.com/

http://demo.nopcommerce.com/

For free you can't beat this.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com)

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked
http://www.oscommerce.com/

It was discussed here also:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143656/whats-the-best-free-and-opensource-php-ecommerce-solution-and-why

Regards

Answer (score -1):

oscommerce- basically many features that you want, they have it. Only thing is it is in plugin format, you need to go to their forum to find the plugin to install.

I would recommend below:

interspire shopping cart- one of the most user friendly cart. Not free, but quality is there. I personally love this a lot.

Magento- is the open source software. Very good quality and functionality. BUT BUT BUT, eat up lot of server memory. If you want to go for this, start from semi dedicated server is your choice.

Comment: osCommerce is extremely vulnerable  and features old code (10+ years old)